# Query returns items in console log, but html is showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined when trying to display on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, parse-platform

Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

The code queries and returns results that should then display in the id "imgs". At the moment I'm getting an

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

error. I've tried, but cannot understand whats causing it or how to fix it.

a url to the page is here http://kudosoo.com/friendslistTEST.html

Driving me mad...

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();  
var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");


    var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
    query.include('toUser');
   // query.include('fromUser');
    //query.include('pic');
    query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
    query.equalTo("status", "Request sent");

         query.find({
              success: function(results) {
        // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
        imageURLs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
          var object = results[i];
          imageURLs.push(object.get('pic'));
        }
     // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
        for(var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++){
           $('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j].get("toUser").pic + "'/>");                 
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
         // show the signup or login page

 </script>

<div id="imgs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using.

```
imageURLs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
          var object = results[i].get("toUser");
         imageURLs.push(object.get("pic"));
        }
     // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
        console.log(imageURLs);
        for(var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++){
          $('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");               
        }
```